# Customize tkinter listbox by adding progress bars

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a listbox, and I would like to have a progress bar inside each line of this listbox. Is there a simple way to do that, or do I have to rewrite the listbox class, or maybe override it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way. A listbox can only contain text.

You can fake it fairly easily with a text widget, since a text widget allows you to embed widgets. For each row you could insert the text, insert a progress bar, and then insert a newline.